# Get values from hash in hash

Tags: ruby

I tried to implement this example in order to compare values:

```
error = system_errors[response_code]
    raise error[:error_class].constantize, error[:error_message]

@system_errors = {100 => { error_class: 'SystemError', error_message = 'A general system error occured.'},
                    101 => { error_class: 'MaintenanceError', error_message = 'System is undergoing maintenance, request could not behandled.'},
                    110 => { error_class: 'AuthenticationError', error_message = 'Login failed. Check your API credentials.'},
                    120 => { error_class: 'ConfigurationError', error_message = 'Configuration error occured, e.g. terminal not configured properly. Check terminal settings.'},
                    200 => { error_class: 'CommunicationError', error_message = 'Communication with issuer failed, please contact support.'},
                    210 => { error_class: 'ConnectionError', error_message = 'Connection to issuer could not be established, please contact support.'},
                    220 => { error_class: 'AccountError', error_message = 'Issuer account data invalid, please contact support.'},
                    220 => { error_class: 'AccountError', error_message = 'Descption: Issuer account data invalid, please contact support.'},
                    230 => { error_class: 'TimeoutError', error_message = 'Issuer does not respond within given timeframe - please reconcile'}}
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => (SyntaxError)
...general system error occured.'},
...                               ^
/Users/response.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
... request could not behandled.'},
...                               ^
    /Users/response.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
... timeframe - please reconcile'}}
...                               ^
/Users/response.rb:45: class definition in method body
    /response.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

What is the proper way to implement this code?
Basically I want to compare values from hash into hash.

Comment: Hm, you literally would have spent significantly less time on figuring this out by actually reading the error message and taking a close look at a line which generated it, than you spent on composing this post. And it's the same with most of your questions (ruby ones, at leaat). Why you keep doing this, is a mystery to me. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Typical for this poster. Then there are answer (or comments) and then... quiet... Check the number of downvotes on his questions (he is in the top 10 of most questions asked if I remember correctly)

Comment: @Kukeltje Hi dude, answering JSF question is not enough so you started Ruby also?

Comment: Learning JSF (or trying to) not enough? Ruby now also?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes sure

Answer (score 1):

Replace every occurrence of `=` with `:` inside hash.

```
@system_errors = {100 => { error_class: 'SystemError', error_message: 'A general system error occured.'},
                101 => { error_class: 'MaintenanceError', error_message: 'System is undergoing maintenance, request could not behandled.'},
                110 => { error_class: 'AuthenticationError', error_message: 'Login failed. Check your API credentials.'},
                120 => { error_class: 'ConfigurationError', error_message: 'Configuration error occured, e.g. terminal not configured properly. Check terminal settings.'},
                200 => { error_class: 'CommunicationError', error_message: 'Communication with issuer failed, please contact support.'},
                210 => { error_class: 'ConnectionError', error_message: 'Connection to issuer could not be established, please contact support.'},
                220 => { error_class: 'AccountError', error_message: 'Issuer account data invalid, please contact support.'},
                220 => { error_class: 'AccountError', error_message: 'Descption: Issuer account data invalid, please contact support.'},
                230 => { error_class: 'TimeoutError', error_message: 'Issuer does not respond within given timeframe - please reconcile'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error: `error_message = '...'`

Must be `error_message: '...'`

```
@system_errors = {100 => { error_class: 'SystemError', error_message: 'A general system error occured.'},
                101 => { error_class: 'MaintenanceError', error_message: 'System is undergoing maintenance, request could not behandled.'},
                110 => { error_class: 'AuthenticationError', error_message: 'Login failed. Check your API credentials.'},
                120 => { error_class: 'ConfigurationError', error_message: 'Configuration error occured, e.g. terminal not configured properly. Check terminal settings.'},
                200 => { error_class: 'CommunicationError', error_message: 'Communication with issuer failed, please contact support.'},
                210 => { error_class: 'ConnectionError', error_message : 'Connection to issuer could not be established, please contact support.'},
                220 => { error_class: 'AccountError', error_message: 'Issuer account data invalid, please contact support.'},
                220 => { error_class: 'AccountError', error_message: 'Descption: Issuer account data invalid, please contact support.'},
                230 => { error_class: 'TimeoutError', error_message: 'Issuer does not respond within given timeframe - please reconcile'}}
```